# Program to read 2 lists and print numbers from lists combined in reverse order

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I've been writing a program where the user enters numbers for two different lists and the the program prints the lists combined and sorts the numbers in reverse order (highest - lowest).

I have managed to write a program but I need a way to change it so the user enters the list in one line instead of multiple lines and then my end result isn't printing in (highest - lowest) it currently only prints (low-high)

see bellow my code

```
a=[]
c=[]
n1=int(input("Enter number of elements:"))
for i in range(1,n1+1):
    b=int(input("Enter element:"))
    a.append(b)
n2=int(input("Enter number of elements:"))
for i in range(1,n2+1):
    d=int(input("Enter element:"))
    c.append(d)
new=a+c
new.sort()
print("Sorted list is:",new)
```

Output

```
Enter number of elements:4
Enter element:1
Enter element:3
Enter element:3
Enter element:6
Enter number of elements:3
Enter element:1
Enter element:4
Enter element:5
Sorted list is: [1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

how am I able to change my code so it looks like this :

```
list 1 : 1 2 3 4
list 2 : 5 6 7 8
output :[ 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: sort in reverse order `new.sort(reverse=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work.  You could also ask for comma separated input instead.

Example input would look like this for each list:
`1 2 3 4 5`

```
lst1 = input("Enter list of space separated numbers:") # input = `2 1 4 7 5 9`
lst2 = input("Enter list of space separated numbers:")
a = [int(i) for i in lst1.split(' ') if i.isdigit()]
c = [int(i) for i in lst2.split(' ') if i.isdigit()]

new= a + c
new.sort(reverse=True)
print("Sorted list is:",new)
```

Comment: You should add a basic control that check if all inputs are positive integers such as `are_digits = [c.isdigit() for c in lst1.replace(' ','')]` and if `all(are_digits)` is `False` then you should ask to re-enter the list

Comment: @soundwave The OP can add checks in if he needs them.  I did edit the list comp to make sure it is only grabbing digit types though.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

To enter the list in one line do something like

```py
a = [int(i) for i in input("list 1: ").split(" ")]
```

and as Albin Paul pointed out in the comments, use

```py
new.sort(reverse=True)
```

to sort from highest to lowest

Answer (score 2):

1.if you want to reverse a sorted array you can use below:

```
new.sort(reverse=True)
```

2. if you just want to reverse a list you can use:

```
new[::-1]#will give you a reverse list

#or else you can use predefined method 
new.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the two list in a single line and split them with spaces. And covert them to int, merge them and order in descending order.

````
list1 = input('Enter List 1:  ')
list2 = input('Enter List 2:  ')
list_1 = list1.split()
list_2 = list2.split()
# print list

list_1 = list(map(int, list_1))
list_2 = list(map(int, list_2))

final_list = list_1 + list_2


# 1
print(sorted(final_list, reverse=True))

# 2
final_list.sort(reverse=True)
print(final_list)```
````